# how to use laravel eloquent to get and display data from other tables

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I was using these codes in my controller to get all the data from my 2 tables and it works fine

```
$All = Customers::with('order')->paginate(10);

return response()->json([
    'code' => 0,
    'success' => true,
    'data' => $All
], 200);
```

Here is how I define the relationship between these 2 tables

```
class Customers extends Model
{
    public function order()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Orders::class, 'customer_id', 'id');
    }
}

class Orders extends Model
{
    public function customers()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Customers::class, 'customer_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

[image]

**Now my desire output is to hide the order id, order timestamps and change the customer_id to customer's name (the customer's name is not in my orders db table).**

I'm using `'data' => DataResource::collection($All)` in my controller and this is my **DataResource**

```
public function toArray($request)
{
    return [
        'id' => $this->id,
        'name' => $this->name,
        'created_at' => $this->created_at,
        'updated_at' => $this->updated_at,
        'order' => $this->order
    ];
}
```

and of course the output is same with the image above.

My database structure:

- **orders table:** 
  [image]
- **customer table:**
  [image]

Can anyone help me with that?

Comment: In future, please add all data that is relevant to the question directly inside the question text. Links to third-party pages and images can get invalid over time, rendering the question useless because answers cannot be verified anymore.

Comment: @Namoshek i try to post images when I posting the question but it is not allow me to put image inside the question so I have no choice to put link. But somehow now it's works

Comment: Embedding images doesn't solve the issue of links getting invalid. What if imgur deleted these images after a few months? Your question and potentially answers as well will not make much sense without the information in the images.

Comment: @Namoshek can you help me with this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57545597/how-to-solve-sqlstate42s22-column-not-found-1054-unknown-column-providers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is simple and basically [a copy of the official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-resources#writing-resources). You simply need to wrap your orders in an `OrderResource` as well.

```
// DataResource
public function toArray($request)
{
    return [
        'id' => $this->id,
        'name' => $this->name,
        'created_at' => $this->created_at,
        'updated_at' => $this->updated_at,
        'order' => OrderResource::collection($this->order)
    ];
}

// OrderResource
public function toArray($request)
{
    return [
        'items' => $this->items,
        'quantity' => $this->quantity
    ];
}
```

I don't really understand why you would want to include the `customer_name` in your orders when it is already present on the customers object one hierarchy above. But if you really want to add it, you should be able to do so with: `'customer_name' => $this->customers->name`.

As a side note: you really should be more consistent with your naming. Why is the resource called `DataResource` when it is about `Customers`? Why is your model called `Customers` in plural form rather than `Customer` in singular, which is the convention (and more logical if you consider that one model represents one customer). Why is your `belongsTo` relation called `customers()` in plural when it returns one customer, while your `hasMany` relation is called `order` whereas it returns one or more orders?

Comment: Thanks for your answer and advise, I will take note on that. But I do have another question for you, may I know the  **''customer_name' => $this->customers->name** customers refer to what?

Comment: It refers to the array in `OrderResource`, which is where you want to return it from.

Comment: no, what I mean is, is it refer to my **customers** table name or **public function customers()** (which in my Orders model) or other thing?

Comment: It refers to the `customers()` function. Laravel allows dynamic access to relations through a property with the same name as the relationship method. So instead of `$order->customers()->getResults()->name`, you can use `$order->customers->name`.

Comment: but how is it **$this->customers->name** and **$this->Customers->name** both works?

Comment: Because PHP is case-insensitive in some regards. That doesn't mean it is considered good to randomly use other casing, though. Stay with the right capitalization wherever possible.